# Apple MacBook Pro will not do updates

Tags: software-update

I have this MacBook Pro running OS X Version 10.9.5 and it works perfect in every way except for one thing; it will not get updates.  When I go to "About This Mac" and click on "software update" it will close out the window and --that is all.  I am back on the desktop.  there is no error messeges, or anything.  Any ideas what I can do to fix this?

Comment: It could be that your computer is too old and there are no more updates for your computer.

Answer (score 1):

Three things to try - report back & we can tweak this answer.

1. Try Launching App Store directly from the Applications folder, rather than via About this Mac.
2. Clean out the App Store prefs & caches...
   Open Terminal & copy/paste each of these 3 lines, hitting Enter after each
   `rm ~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.appstore.plist`
   `rm ~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.storeagent.plist`
   `rm ~/Library/Cookies/com.apple.appstore.plist`
   and again for the caches
   `rm -r ~/Library/Caches/com.apple.appstore`
   `rm -r ~/Library/Caches/com.apple.storeagent`
3. Make a new admin account...
   System Prefs > Users & Groups
   Unlock the prefs, if locked, & click the plus button at the bottom.
   Set up a new Admin [not Standard] account, then try logging yourself out & into that account instead.
   Test method 1.

Comment: Ok I tried all three suggestions and here are the results:  number one: When I clicked on the app store it just went back to the desktop - I noticed that the app store icon on the bottom bounced up once and that was all

Comment: Suggestion 2: I attempted to open terminal but it does the same thing - just goes back to the desktop - I get the same results after creating another admin account.

Comment: Try re-applying the [combo updater for 10.9.5](https://support.apple.com/kb/dl1760?)

Comment: Ok, I downloaded and attempted to re-apply the combo updater but I get the error message: OS X Update combined can't by installed on this disk. This volume does not meet the requirements for this update."

Comment: I'd be tempted to raise that last comment as a new question; with a link back to this one. I'd say the next step would be to find out **why** you're getting that message, but I'm not sure myself.